# Increase size of confetti like mouse effect

Tags: javascript

I am new to js, I would like to increase the size of the confetti like animation shown here

```
var colour="random"; // "random" can be replaced with any valid colour ie: "red"...
var sparkles=100;// increase or decrease for number of sparkles falling

var x=ox=800;
var y=oy=300;
var swide=800;
var shigh=600;
var sleft=sdown=0;
var tiny=new Array();
var star=new Array();
var starv=new Array();
var starx=new Array();
var stary=new Array();
var tinyx=new Array();
var tinyy=new Array();
var tinyv=new Array();

colours=new Array('#ff0000','#00ff00','#ffffff','#ff00ff','#ffa500','#ffff00','#00ff00','#ffffff','#ff00ff')

n = 0;
y = 0;
x = 0;
n6=(document.getElementById&&!document.all);
ns=(document.layers);
ie=(document.all);
d=(ns||ie)?'document.':'document.getElementById("';
a=(ns||n6)?'':'all.';
n6r=(n6)?'")':'';
s=(ns)?'':'.style';

// if (ns){
//  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
//      document.write('<layer name="dots'+i+'" top=0 left=0 width='+i/2+' height='+i/2+' bgcolor=#ff0000></layer>');
// }

// if (ie)
//  document.write('<div id="con" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px"><div style="position:relative">');

if (ie||n6){
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        document.write('<div id="dots'+i+'" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+i/2+'px;height:'+i/2+'px;background:#ff0000;font-size:'+i/2+'"></div>');
}

if (ie)
    document.write('</div></div>');
(ns||n6)?window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE):0;

function Mouse(evnt){

    y = (ns||n6)?evnt.pageY+4 - window.pageYOffset:event.y+4;
    x = (ns||n6)?evnt.pageX+1:event.x+1;
}

(ns)?window.onMouseMove=Mouse:document.onmousemove=Mouse;

function animate(){

    o=(ns||n6)?window.pageYOffset:0;

    if (ie)con.style.top=document.body.scrollTop +'px';

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

        var temp1 = eval(d+a+"dots"+i+n6r+s);

        randcolours = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];

        (ns)?temp1.bgColor = randcolours:temp1.background = randcolours;

        if (i < n-1){

            var temp2 = eval(d+a+"dots"+(i+1)+n6r+s);
            temp1.top = parseInt(temp2.top) + 'px';
            temp1.left = parseInt(temp2.left) + 'px';

        }
        else{

            temp1.top = y+o + 'px';
            temp1.left = x + 'px';
        }
    }

    setTimeout("animate()",10);
}

animate();

window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
    var i, rats, rlef, rdow;
    for (var i=0; i<sparkles; i++) {
        var rats=createDiv(3, 3);
        rats.style.visibility="hidden";
        rats.style.zIndex="999";
        document.body.appendChild(tiny[i]=rats);
        starv[i]=0;
        tinyv[i]=0;
        var rats=createDiv(5, 5);
        rats.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
        rats.style.visibility="hidden";
        rats.style.zIndex="999";
        var rlef=createDiv(5, 5);
        var rdow=createDiv(5, 5);
        rats.appendChild(rlef);
        rats.appendChild(rdow);
        rlef.style.top="2px";
        rlef.style.left="0px";
        rdow.style.top="0px";
        rdow.style.left="2px";
        document.body.appendChild(star[i]=rats);
    }
    set_width();
    sparkle();
}}

function sparkle() {
    var c;
    if (Math.abs(x-ox)>1 || Math.abs(y-oy)>1) {
        ox=x;
        oy=y;
        for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) if (!starv[c]) {
            star[c].style.left=(starx[c]=x) +"px";
            star[c].style.top=(stary[c]=y+1)+"px";
            star[c].style.clip="rect(0px, 5px, 5px, 0px)";
            star[c].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor=star[c].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor=(colour=="random")?newColour():colour;
            star[c].style.visibility="visible";
            starv[c]=100; // fade out value
            break;
        }
    }
    for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) {
        if (starv[c]) update_star(c);
        if (tinyv[c]) update_tiny(c);
    }
    setTimeout("sparkle()", 20); // speed 40
}

function update_star(i) {
    if (--starv[i]==25) star[i].style.clip="rect(1px, 4px, 4px, 1px)";
    if (starv[i]) {
        stary[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
        starx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
        if (stary[i]<shigh+sdown) {
            star[i].style.top=stary[i]+"px";
            star[i].style.left=starx[i]+"px";
        }
        else {
            star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
            starv[i]=0;
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        tinyv[i]=50;
        tiny[i].style.top=(tinyy[i]=stary[i])+"px";
        tiny[i].style.left=(tinyx[i]=starx[i])+"px";
        tiny[i].style.width="2px";
        tiny[i].style.height="2px";
        tiny[i].style.backgroundColor=star[i].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor;
        star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
        tiny[i].style.visibility="visible"
    }
}

function update_tiny(i) {
    if (--tinyv[i]==25) {
        tiny[i].style.width="1px";
        tiny[i].style.height="1px";
    }
    if (tinyv[i]) {
        tinyy[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
        tinyx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
        if (tinyy[i]<shigh+sdown) {
            tiny[i].style.top=tinyy[i]+"px";
            tiny[i].style.left=tinyx[i]+"px";
        }
        else {
            tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
            tinyv[i]=0;
            return;
        }
    }
    else tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
}

document.onmousemove=mouse;
function mouse(e) {
    if (e) {
        y=e.pageY;
        x=e.pageX;
    }
    else {
        set_scroll();
        y=event.y+sdown;
        x=event.x+sleft;
    }
}

window.onscroll=set_scroll;
function set_scroll() {
    if (typeof(self.pageYOffset)=='number') {
        sdown=self.pageYOffset;
        sleft=self.pageXOffset;
    }
    else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollLeft)) {
        sdown=document.body.scrollTop;
        sleft=document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
    else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)) {
        sleft=document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        sdown=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    else {
        sdown=0;
        sleft=0;
    }
}

window.onresize=set_width;
function set_width() {
    var sw_min=999999;
    var sh_min=999999;
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth>0) sw_min=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (document.documentElement.clientHeight>0) sh_min=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if (typeof(self.innerWidth)=='number' && self.innerWidth) {
        if (self.innerWidth>0 && self.innerWidth<sw_min) sw_min=self.innerWidth;
        if (self.innerHeight>0 && self.innerHeight<sh_min) sh_min=self.innerHeight;
    }
    if (document.body.clientWidth) {
        if (document.body.clientWidth>0 && document.body.clientWidth<sw_min) sw_min=document.body.clientWidth;
        if (document.body.clientHeight>0 && document.body.clientHeight<sh_min) sh_min=document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    if (sw_min==999999 || sh_min==999999) {
        sw_min=800;
        sh_min=600;
    }
    swide=sw_min;
    shigh=sh_min;
}

function createDiv(height, width) {
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div.style.position="absolute";
    div.style.height=height+"px";
    div.style.width=width+"px";
    div.style.overflow="hidden";
    return (div);
}

function newColour() {
    var c=new Array();
    c[0]=255;
    c[1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    c[2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*(256-c[1]/2));
    c.sort(function(){return (0.5 - Math.random());});
    return ("rgb("+c[0]+", "+c[1]+", "+c[2]+")");
}
// ]]>
```

the rest of the code can be found here:

https://codepen.io/dimitris_ps-the-animator/pen/KKgQdeR

As a second part of the question, is there a way to substitute the heart like objects with confetti like.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing -

```
star[c].style.clip="rect(0px, 5px, 5px, 0px)";
```

To

```
star[c].style.clip="rect(0px, 10px, 10px, 0px)";
```

And

```
createDiv(5, 5);
```

To

```
createDiv(10, 10);
```

Wherever you find it.